# Where should be contained methods for manipulating (algorithms, CRUD operations, manipulating records from database etc) data in MVC pattern?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture

Where should be contained methods for manipulating data(algorithms, CRUD operations, connections with databases, manipulating records from database etc.) in MVC pattern? In Controller?

Comment: I would suggest trying to learn [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) first and then come back here and ask more specific questions, if you will still have them. From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/26572063).

Comment: In the simplest terms, these firmly belong in your controller. That's _precisely_ what the controller is for. By contrast, your _models_ should be exclusively about the storing the data, and your views should be exclusively about rendering the data. There are some squiggly areas like view logic, but generally everything else belongs in your controller. That said, often, your controller will simply be coordinating activities from other services, such as a database repository. The Wikipedia article that @sanitizedUser recommended is definitely a good place to start.